# Monitor the Date in Flex for a change

Tags: apache-flex, datetime, flex3, air, timer

In Flex/ActionScript 3, is there a better way to monitor the date/time to determine if the date has changed to the next day by creating a timer that dispatches every minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good example to do just that: [Sample clock](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=08_Dates_and_times_5.html)

Comment: So yes, I think the Timer is the best way to go.